# Search parameter in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcgrid.net

I'm trying to figure out one of package in ASP.Net MVC 5 called [MVC.Grid](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation).

I have model like below :

```
public class MasterCustomer
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And controller like this :

```
public class MasterCustomersController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: MasterCustomers
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.MasterCustomers.ToList());

        return View(db.MasterCustomers.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult IndexGrid(String search)
    {
        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.MasterCustomers.Find(search));
    }
}
```

I want to separate this into two questions:

1. How this controller works, when I do sort or search, it returns correctly even there is no controller handle for the action. Example :

   `http://localhost/MasterCustomers?search=&sort=code&order=asc&_=1533109639307`
   `http://localhost/MasterCustomers?search=&sort=code&order=asc&code-contains=tes&code-op=&code-contains=&_=1533109639308`

   even there is no `sort` and `order` or `contains` action in my controller, this action working nicely.
2. sadly one of [GlobalSearch](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/GlobalSearch) action `search` didn't work correctly. It returns all data no matter what I typed. Example :
   `http://localhost/MasterCustomers?search=sdfasdfasdfasdfsadwrh2w3rwegaweg&_=1533109639344`

If I know how question in no. 1 works maybe I can figure out the question in no.2.

Comment: Aside: we appreciate any efforts at spell-checking and brevity of writing, as per some of my prior edits. The contraction of "I am" is "I'm", which contains an apostrophe. We prefer questions without thanks, appreciation and other niceties.

Comment: The general advice I usually offer folks is: _note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 already have a built-in function to determine if a a request is Ajax. You can use `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [full source code](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid) is available for this Open Source Project, so if you have some patience, you could find out yourself. Basically, by executing [`Html.Grid(Model)`](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid/blob/develop/src/Mvc.Grid.Core/Html/MvcGridExtensions.cs) in the View, a new [`HtmlGrid`](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid/blob/develop/src/Mvc.Grid.Core/Grids/HtmlGrid.cs) is constructed, which has raw access to your query parameters:

   ```
   grid.Query = new NameValueCollection(grid.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString);
   ```

   so these don't have to be Route Attributes.
2. Your Ajax Check ("`if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-...`") appears to be incorrect, where did you get that from? The implementation example on the page you provided is clearly different. By calling `Index` instead of `IndexGrid` as it's supposed to be, you lose the search parameter

Change your `index` to :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

and `IndexGrid` to :

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult IndexGrid(String search)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.MasterCustomers.ToList());
    else
        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.MasterCustomers.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(search) || x.Name.Contains(search)).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Hi there, the example is from here http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/SourceUrl
Im trying to combine normal search and global search.
I will try some of your suggestion and will update soon

Comment: Hi there, your clue give me an answer. I added some answer from your clues. Please accept it so I can mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: OK I understand, you got your example from http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/SourceUrl but I was looking at Global Search ( http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/GlobalSearch ) where it definitely looks different, but anyway, glad it helped